# Forwarding email based on incoming address

Tags: email, exim

I'm running a CentOS5 (soon to be CentOS7) VPS so need the solution to be specific to one domain and not systemwide affecting email services for other domains.  i.e. no tweaking of global services.

I want to forward incoming email arriving at a unique/unshared mydomain.com using the bit before the @ sign and a MySQL database to determine the "real" destination address.

Example:  Incoming email to 123456@mydomain.com - customer 123456 looked up in database, resolved to johndoe@theirdomain.com and email is forwarded there unmodified (except for the delivery address).

There are tens of thousands of variations on 123456 so the method must be dynamic.

Emails may be text, HTML and may have attachments.

Comment: Which MTA/SMTP server do you use? [postfix/sendmail/exim/...] AFAIK 1) sendmail does not support mysql queries 2) postfix should handle it

Comment: exim ... but already your suggestion has me googling 'exim mysql' and 'postfix mysql' so has hopefully set me off in the right direction.

Comment: Would still appreciate pointers from anyone else who has done anything like this.